# Windows File open SLOW

Tags: find-file, performance

Windows 10
Emacs 27.1

From `C-x C-f File`
Till seeing the file actually open can take almost a minute!

Tried emacs instead of runemacs.
Also Menu-file-visit
All the same

I think there's some Mcafee stuff running
(sorry don't know too much... Office machine!
Just assume standard "corporate setup"??
In any case could'nt get task manager to show some rogue 100% process. But I'm terrible at using windows effectively and am open to being educated )

And maybe this question will find better answers on superuser?? Can move it if that's so...

Is there a more emacs-centric (rather than task-manager — windows centric) way of finding out what emacs is up-to in that long 1 minute?

Comment: You can [profile](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Profiling) the code. You can also run with `emacs -q` to avoid your init file and see if the problem lies there.

Comment: Many years ago I used [stracent](https://github.com/ipankajg/stracent) (I'm not sure if it was this version) to see why some Windows programs were taking so long and saw that the antivirus was hooking into every call. I couldn't see _what_ it was doing, all I could do was to confirm that the antivirus was the malware. Unfortunately there's usually nothing you can do about that.

Comment: Make sure you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (or `runemacs -Q`) - no init file. If you no longer see the problem then bisect your init file to find the culprit. (Always suspect your init file first.) Also, please state whether you saw the same problem with an earlier Emacs release, or any other info you think might be relevant.

Comment: Thanks @nickd. Using the profiler I find it's not "find-file" that is slow; it's org-mode. FF a .txt file is instant and simply putting the scratch (or any other) buffer into org-mode takes forever! (Almost virgin install: just emacs 27.1 no init; built-in org version 9.3)